# Unit test a SelectList object returned as JsonResult

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I'm struggling to test the method below:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonObjectsFromOffices(int siteId)
{
    IEnumerable<Office> officeList; 

    officeList = repository.Offices
        .Where(o => o.SiteID == siteId)
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name);

    return Json(new SelectList(officeList, "OfficeID", "Name"));
}
```

Using Moq and xUnit, I have the following test

```
//Arrange
Mock<IFormRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IFormRepository>();
var mockUserMgr = GetMockUserManager();
var userValid = new CustomUserValidator();
var passwordValid = new CustomPasswordValidator();
var passwordHash = new PasswordHasher<AppUser>();
mockRepo.Setup(m => m.Offices).Returns(new Office[]
{
    new Office {OfficeID = 2, SiteID = 2, Name = "Bravo"},
    new Office {OfficeID = 1, SiteID = 1, Name = "Alpha"},
    new Office {OfficeID = 3, SiteID = 1, Name = "Charlie"}
}.AsQueryable<Office>());

AdminController controller = new AdminController(mockUserMgr.Object, userValid, passwordValid, passwordHash, mockRepo.Object);

//Act
var jsonObj = controller.GetJsonObjectsFromOffices(1);

//'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0.' error on line below
//var selectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObj.Value.ToString());
```

The goal on the Assert portion of the test would be to verify that the correct number of list items was returned (i.e. two items corresponding to `SiteID = 1`).

The `jsonObj` is a `JsonResult` type, with a value of `{Microsoft.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList}`. Within the `SelectList`, the correct `Items` are produced, but I don't know how to access them to count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value stored in the result would be of the type passed to it.

Cast the expected value to the expected type and do the assertions on that if it cast successfully

```
//...code removed for brevity

//Act
var jsonResult = controller.GetJsonObjectsFromOffices(1);

//Assert
var selectList = jsonResult.Value as SelectList;
Assert.NotNull(selectList); //<-- cast was successful

var expected = 2;
var actual = selectList.Count();

Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
```

Comment: I fixed it in the answer.